# UTF-8 or windows-1252?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

I have windows XP at home - home ed, with SP3. In any case, at College, they have windows 7. So, basically when I saved my documents and brought them here, things messed up. I was writing up a short bio.

I was coding my website, and so as usual I had used charset utf-8, the standard. But when I get home and I verify my website (locally), I see the weird characters appear! The triangle and the question mark inside it. So, then I'm like WTF? So I decide to go online and check which charset is better. So randomly, I fall onto windows-1252. Voila, it worked! But then, I decided to re-use charset utf-8, being the standard. I don't want to mess up my website lol.

So I basically go back inside my html document, just to notice that very weird characters appeared. So I delete them and replace them with the the apostrophe that were originally there. Finally, I check my website, and the apostrophes correctly appear.

So, what the hell is going on??? And should I keep using utf-8?

Comment: How are you testing this? Where exactly does it mess up? What applications are involved?

Comment: Simply always use good editor to edit your text, and be sure to save it in UTF-8, and you will be fine. On Windows, I would recommend [`Notepad++`](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: Have a read of this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Anything other than Unicode has no future in the long run anyway. Systems keep replacing anything with Unicode nowadays, since working with tons of different charsets always ends up to be PITA at some point of tie.

Comment: did you use MS/Word to edit any of that text, if so you might be getting those M$ "Smart Quotes"

Comment: note for php: you need to save everything in UTF-8 without BOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the content of the webpage is actually encoded as Windows-1252 by whatever editor you are using, but you are manually writing a `<meta>` tag that states UTF-8 instead.  That would account for the behavior you describe.  An explicit charset declaration must match the actual encoding used by the data.  When you tell your editor to save the document, make sure it is saving the data in the correct encoding you are expecting.  Some editors do support multiple encodings, so don't just blindly use a default encoding if multiple encodings are available.

Comment: Wow! I have not seen your reply. This is VERY strange. Thank you for answering! And sorry for the delay.

Yes, that was exactly the problem. I realized that much later. And you are validating that this was indeed the problem :)